# Laravel 5 - Pretty paginator

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

So I'm trying to obtain pagination in **Laravel 5** with pretty urls like `localhost/ads/1` where `1` stands for the page.

Up to my understanding, such an operation would require an overloading of `AbstractPaginator`, or `LengthAwarePaginator`, to aim at a modification of `Database\Query\Builder`.

Am I missing something, a binding or a dependency injection, or should there be the possibility to change the paginator we want to be used?

Comment: Could you use `mod_rewrite` to convert the URL to the correct query string? Convert it internally to `localhost/ads?page=1`.

Comment: @BenHarold Sure, that would work to redirect links. However, it won't change the problem of the generation of the links, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I had to code myself a Paginator. I'm posting here my solution, should it help anybody.

Note that the solution, while functional, requires some care for practical use (about validation); the class is simplified here to highlight the mechanism.

```
<?php namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\BootstrapThreePresenter;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as BasePaginator;

class Paginator extends BasePaginator{



     /**
     * Create a new paginator instance.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $items
     * @param  int  $perPage
     * @param  string $path Base path
     * @param  int $page
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($items, $perPage, $path, $page){
        // Set the "real" items that will appear here
        $trueItems = [];

        // That is, add the correct items
        for ( $i = $perPage*($page-1) ; $i < min(count($items),$perPage*$page) ; $i++ ){
            $trueItems[] = $items[$i];
        }

        // Set path as provided
        $this->path = $path;

        // Call parent
        parent::__construct($trueItems,count($items),$perPage);

        // Override "guessing" of page
        $this->currentPage = $page;
    }

    /**
     * Get a URL for a given page number.
     *
     * @param  int  $page
     * @return string
     */
    public function url($page){
        if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;

        return $this->path.$page;
    }
}
```

To use the class, you can define a route

```
Route::get('items/{page}','MyController@getElements');
```

Then in the said controller, in `getElements`:

```
$items = new Paginator(Model::all(),$numberElementsPerPage,url('items'),$page);
```

Then, you can dispose of your elements as you normally would.
Note: I added a path option, in order to integrate more complex pretty url designs.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't that mean that you have to load the entire table into memory before you can paginate what you want?

Comment: `Model::all` returns the whole set... that's overkill isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for laravel 5.3 without performance negatives:
`PlumPrettyUrlPaginator.php`

```
<?php
namespace Plum\Cmc\Paginator;

use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class PlumPrettyUrlPaginator extends LengthAwarePaginator{

  /**
   * basically a copy of LengthAwarePaginator constructor and then replacing all in our own
   */
  public function __construct(LengthAwarePaginator $p, $path, $currentPage = null) {

    $this->total = $p->total;
    $this->perPage = $p->perPage;
    $this->lastPage = (int) ceil($p->total / $p->perPage);
//    $this->path = ((stripos(strrev($p->path), '/') === 0) ? $p->path : $p->path.'/');
    $this->path = $path;
    $this->currentPage = $p->setCurrentPage($currentPage ?? $p->currentPage, $p->pageName);
    $this->items = $p->items;
  }

  public function url($page){
    if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;
    return $this->path.$page;
  }
}
```

routes:

```
Route::get('/', [ function (Request $request) {
  $data = PlumSearchService::PrepareSearchView($request);
  return view('inventory.search_products', $data);
}]);


Route::get('/page/{pageNr}', [ function (Request $request, int $pageNr) {
  $data = PlumSearchService::PrepareSearchView($request, false, $pageNr);
  return view('inventory.search_products', $data);
}]);
```

then in the `PlumSearchService`

```
$query = Product::select('product.*') //...
       $paginator = $query->paginate(15, ['*'], 'page', $pageNr);
        $products = new PlumPrettyUrlPaginator($paginator, '/page/', $pageNr);
```

Answer (score -5):

Remove this `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` code line from **.htaccess**.

Comment: That line has nothing to do with the question.